# Which HTML elements can't have an id or class?

Tags: html

According to [the HTML4 spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/struct/global.html),

> Almost every HTML element may be assigned identifier and class information.

What it doesn't say is which elements *can't* have an id or class. Which elements can't?

Comment: IIRC, it's those elements which are only valid in `<head>` - title, link, meta, etc. Not posting as an answer because I'm not sure and don't have a handy source to cite.

Comment: I think thios wording is used as an escape clause so that *if* there is a future element that for whatever reason can't have an id or class attribute associated with it, that their documentation would still hold true.

Comment: @Martin Not so. The OP didn't specify where that quotation came from, but if you look at the quote and source in my answer, you will see that global attributes are explicitly allowed everywhere.

Comment: The Quote came [from here](https://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/struct/global.html) or [here](https://www.w3.org/TR/WD-html40-970708/struct/global.html) relating to HTML4 documents. @ScottMarcus. Your answer is good but your answer specifically deals with HTML5 documents so there may be divergence.

Comment: @Martin Actually, if you look at the bottom of the MDN documentation (which I provided a link to), it does explicitly show where `id` was **not** allowed in HTML 4.01. Similarly, if you look at the docs for `class`, at the bottom of the doc it specifically states where `class` can not be used in HTML 4.01.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your question specifically mentions the HTML 4.01 standard. If you look at the bottom of the documentation for `id` and `class` at **[MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes)**, you'll see a table of which specifications these attributes are present in. The table shows:[image]

The current version of HTML is HTML 5.x, which has been standardized for several years now and formally introduced "global attributes". **In that standard, global attributes, can be used anywhere** **[according to the documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes)** and the actual **[HTML specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#global-attributes)**, but may not have any impact depending on where you use them:

> Global attributes are attributes common to all HTML elements; they can
>   be used on all elements, though the attributes may have no effect on
>   some elements.

For all practical purposes, everything in the `body` (including `body`) can have an `id` and/or a `class`, `head` *can* have an `id`, but given that there is only one `head` in a document (and only one `body` for that matter), that is never really needed. Nothing outside of the body would ever need a `class`.

Comment: But `html` can have id and class, too. It just seems semantically weird when they're meaningless for `head`.

Comment: @DavidEhrmann If you read the docs, you'll see that technically `id` and `class` should not be used to convey semantics. Additionally, the docs state that global attributes may even be used on elements that, themselves are invalid. It's really just a way of not imposing strict limits when none are needed. You're right, adding `id` and `class` to `<html>` makes no sense. And, that's why, in the real world, no one does that.